# How to focus/blur on a component in ember integration tests?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, phantomjs, ember-testing, ember-components

How can I trigger focus and blur events while testing an Ember.js component?

`this.$().focus();` or `this.$('input').focus();` seems working but behaves different in phantomjs and chrome.

Also `this.$().blur();` or `this.$().focusout();` seems not working both phantomjs and chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of Ember have test helpers which can be used to focus or blur.

```
... 
import { find, focus, blur, render } from '@ember/test-helpers';


module('Integration | Component | example-input', function(hooks) {
  
  test('it can be focused', async function(assert) {
    await render(hbs`<myInput />`);
    const input = find('input')
    
    await focus(input)
    await blur(input)
  });
  
});
```

blur: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#blur

focus: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#focus

Answer (score 1):

give it a try with `trigger` instead, it worked for me

```
  this.$('input').focusout();
  this.$('input').blur();
  this.$('input').trigger('focusout');
  this.$('input').trigger('blur');
  this.$('input').trigger('keyup'); // another event that you can trigger
```

[more information](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/testing/testing-components/)